# Multi-threaded one reader and one writer using boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm programming in C++ on linux. My program uses two threads when one reads and writes to a shared data-structure. The  data-structure is from type - Boost::bimaps::unordered_set_of . 
So my question is whether I need to worry regarding any synchronizing issues. I.E, do I need to protect the read and write fro the data-structure with locks (or something like that)? Or maybe I will work fine without any use in mutexes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should work with the mutex provided by boost

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts

Answer (score 0):

In common with the standard containers, Boost.Bimap does not provide thread synchronisation. You will have to provide that yourself.